# Robotium activity testing which depends from data in SQLite

Tags: android, sqlite, testing, android-activity, robotium

I want to write Robotium test case for my activity. Test case extends stadard `ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2` as shown in Robotium samples. Activity represents a data-value object which persisted in locale storage and must take an object id as parameter in intent extras. Later in `onCreate` data-value object will be obtained from DB by this id.

Therefore, in `setUp` method i want to create mocked data-value object, persist it into local storage and pass their id into activity via intent extras. But for persisting i need a `Context` instance. Only one way to do this in `ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2` is use `getActivity()` for this. But this will create an instance of my activity before than mocked object will be persisted.

What can i do in this situation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Context without calling `getActivity` can be obtained from `getInstrumentation().getTargetContext()`

Comment: Creating a DB helper with this context and inserting data is not working. The data is still not picked up by the activity when it starts. I am trying to do something with the database when the activity starts.

Comment: I realized that I was using `getActivity()` before `getInstrumentation().getTargetContext()`. That's why it was not working for me. Sorry for the down vote! Will upvote when my edit is peer reviewed.